# Does anybody know which file to add CSS <link> and JS <style> tags to in Jetbox v2.1?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am updating a client site that uses [Jetbox CMS v2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jetboxone/).

I need to add `<script>` and `<link>` tags in the `<head>` section, but cannot for the life of me find which file to edit. There are numerous `tpl` files and the CMS seems rather confusing.

I tried editing `index.php` with the following:

```
//I am pretty sure that this replaces {var_name} in the view 
//with the second argument content
$t->set_var("var_name", "var_name content here");
```

I just can't find the correct file to insert `{var_name}` in...

Thanks to anybody who can help!

P.S. The Jetbox CMS is opensource and has been abandoned, so I can't find any forums or support sites for it.

**Edit**

Well, perhaps *somebody* will actually read this... haha.

While the accepted solution *probably* is the normal solution, I could not find the template file that works for sub-pages (which are called "Links Categories" for some strange reason).

I ended up "piggy-backing" the `<script>` and `<link>` tags onto a `{baseurl}` variable, which is included in the `<head>` section. Unfortunately, I was trying to implement [Lightbox2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/), but it did not work because of some strange IE8 error that prevents Lightbox2 from working correctly when the `<script>` tags come before `<meta>` tags. Since I could not include the `<script>` tags after the `<meta>` tags because I couldn't find the correct template to edit, I just scrapped Lightbox2 for this project. It wasn't a required part of the project, just something extra I was trying to add.

Oh well.

Jetbox seems like a decent CMS for what it is/was, but the naming of sections is odd and un-intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I downloaded the cms for kicks and looking at it rapidely this file: main_tpl.html.
Seems to be where you would want to inject this code. 
The structure of this cms seems pretty simple in that there is a php file with logic and html files with views. So when ever you set something like that in a php file look for ther corresponding html.

In this setup tpl = template.

Heres how I would do it in the default setup I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>{pagetitle}</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
{baseurl}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
{var_name}
```

So your variable right there and it should work. There is already one {baseurl} in there.

Comment: @lzngood - Thanks for looking! I wasn't sure anybody would. Yes, I think you are correct in your example. Although, when I edit `index.php` and `main_tpl.html` nothing happens. There are files in the `templates` directory, which seem to be for multiple "themes". I am digging through those now.

Comment: @letseafood yeah if its anything like wordpress check in the themes folder (find the one you are using or just try them out) and it will be there for sure.

Comment: @letseafood sadly there is no themes folder in what I downloaded so I cannot help you there.

Comment: @lzngood - It's okay, you helped me confirm I am on the right track, and that is great.